# Is there an 'updated Railscast episode source code' site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I've searched for railscast 198 updated to rails 3, I can find some snippets here and there but can't find anything for the full source code.. hey it's worth a search; I'm a noob and don't know all the changes that transitioning rails 2 to rails 3 takes.

I run into the problem periodically where I want to use the method in a Railscast episode, but it's for an older version of rails, and run into a few bumps along the way.  I've benefited from railscasts more than any information on rails out there, (even stackoverflow is distant 2nd), but this, it seems to me, is the biggest problem with railscasts.  Anyone should be able to update the episode source code, it would be great if it would be easy for others to find.

Is there a site or group of people or easy way to find the fork that updates the full episode source code to the current version of rails?  +1 if you would use this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes

Ryan usually updates his casts(198 was an updated version of 165) so if anyone has it, it's him.

Comment: I've seen his updated episodes from time to time, and they're great! If the episodes are open-source, where would I find the rails 3 versions if anyone else updates them?

Comment: you can check the network of each of his repos to check who forked and see if they have a rails3 version